# Ruby on Rails: Xpath: Could not retrieve XPath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, cucumber

This is the error I get:

```
NativeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve XPath >//id[@class='open'//@id='status_open']< on HtmlPage(http://cucumber.test.com/proposals/view-me/edit#)@17325460 (Culerity::CulerityException)
```

This is my Cucumber command

```
Then the "li" tag with the id "status_open" should have the class "open"
```

This is my step definition

```
Then /^the "([^\"]*)" tag with the id "([^\"]*)" should have the class "([^\"]*)"$/ do |tag,id,clas|


if page.respond_to? :should
      page.should have_xpath("//#{tag}[@class='#{clas}',@id='#{id}']")
    else
      assert page.have_xpath("//#{tag}[@class='#{clas}',@id='#{id}']")
    end
end
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<li class="open" id="status_open">
                      <a href="#">
                        Open
                      </a>
                    </li>
```

it seems like it should work, based on this tutoraial:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//id[@class='open'//@id='status_open']`

is not a syntactically correct XPath expression.

**I have to guess... Maybe you wanted**:

`//li[@class='open' and @id='status_open']`